# Flask_oidc gives `Errno 99 Cannot assign requested address` when run in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, openid-connect

**Goal:**

Use OIDC from a Flask app running in a Docker container.

**Background:**

I'm building a web application with Flask and want to use Keycloak to provide access. For this I use the Python library flask_oidc.

All services are run locally with a docker-compose file:

- Gunicorn that runs the Flask application (port 5000)
- Keycloak (port 8080)

I followed the example of https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/145dc9aa857b831ff2eff221b79d179a and even reduced my app to just this.

**Problem:**

1. *Start all services*
2. Navigate to the service that requires login (`/private` in the example)
3. The user is rerouted to the Keycloud server prompting to log in.
4. The user logs in.
5. Keycloak routes the user *back* to the app (`/oidc_callback`)
6. !!! The Flask app crashes with an `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address` error.

This is caused deep down in `flask_oidc` > `oauth2client` > `httplib2` when trying to connect to the Keycloak server.

What I *think* is happening is that the library tries to open a connection with the Keycloak server, but tries to bind this to `localhost`. This probably fails, since inside the Docker container the applications are bound to `0.0.0.0`.

**What I tried:**

[**WORKS**] Run the Gunicorn/Flask app outside of a container, and run the Keylcoak inside a container.

This shows (to me) that all my settings and the code are *fine*, but that the problem is somewhere in the interaction between Docker<-->flask_oidc+.

**Question**:
Can anyone explain this? I really hope that someone has a working setup (Flask inside docker with flask_oidc), and is willing to share this.

**UPDATE [5-12-2018]**
I think I figured it out. I used PyOIDC to manually go through all the steps and be able to debug.

When running both services in Docker on your own computer (`localhost`) you get a conflict:

- Users go to `localhost:8080` to find Keycloak and `localhost:5000` to find the App.
- The Flask app runs inside the container, and `localhost` doesn't resolve to the *host* but rather to itself inside the container.
- You *can* let Flask connect to `http://keycloak/` using the network in the container, *but* then it returns all the configuration under this domain. Which is bad, because to the outside world it should be `localhost:8080`.

Now, if you actually have domain names (for example keycloak.awesome.app and app.awesome.app) I think it'll just work fine, since it'll use an outside DNS to resolve it to an IP address, which is the correct machine.

**Bonus:** PyOIDC can retrieve the provider configuration from the Keycloak, so no more manual typing for this. Yay!

**New setup**
For local development I decided to make a little setup as follows:

(1) Add to `/etc/hosts`:
`127.0.0.1    keycloak.dev.local
 127.0.0.1    app.dev.local`

(2) Add to your Flask service in the `docker-compose.yml`:
`extra_hosts: #host.docker.internal is not accepted.
     - "keycloak.dev.local:<YOUR IP ADRESS>"
     - "app.dev.local:<YOUR IP ADRESS>"`

(=) Now, both you and the Flask application can access `keycloak.dev.local` and can proper reponses!

Note that I would still prefer a *nicer* solution. This setup fails as soon as my ip address changes.

Comment: It looks to me that this problem relies in `flask-oidc`.

Comment: Thank you Rubenz!!! You saved my day! I had the same problem (ok with gunicorn and docker but not from docker). Pointing my flask-oidc url to http://keycloak.dev.local:$port and using the docker-compose with extrahost like you pointed worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

flask-oidc gets token endpoint configuration from the client secrets file.

I managed to make it work by making the following changes:

1. Created a docker network for the **flask app** and **keycloak** containers;
2. Edited the attributes **userinfo_uri**, **token_uri** and **token_introspection_uri**, replacing the hostname with the keycloak container hostname (i'm using docker-compose, in this case the keycloak container hostname is the service name).

Example:

```
{
  "web": {
    "auth_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/REMOVED/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "client_id": "flask-client",
    "client_secret": "REMOVED",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:5000/oidc_callback"],
    "userinfo_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/REMOVED/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "token_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/REMOVED/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/REMOVED/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
  }
}
```

Now it connects through the docker network to exchange token info.